# ArcGIS Javascript Measure Widget - Location tool shows repeating icons

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, html

I am using the measurement widget in my ArcGIS Javascript application, but am having issues with appearance of the Location Tool.  Everything works the way it should but for some reason when using the Location Tool, the mouse and green marker icons show up twice rather than once like in this sandbox (http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=widget_measurement).  My widget ends up looking like this: [image]

Does anyone know why this would be happening or how I can fix it?  I looked in my Firefox console's HTML tab to see that both icons do show up twice for some reason.

Comment: I have figured out using the Firefox HTML inspector tool in the console that the images for the icons for some reason repeat themselves.  After I startup the measure widget, I attempted to add the code seen below, but the icons still repeat.

$('td[dojoattachpoint="mouseCell"]').children().eq(1).remove();
$('td[dojoattachpoint="pinCell"]').children().eq(1).remove();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem - I ended up needing to adjust my HTML code. All I really did was added a div around the title pane and measurement widget div, and the double icon went away.